# Exporting blender project to unity

Tags: materials, unity

I'm a student working on blender and unity right now and I made a copy of a sky island I liked to use as a terrain for me to work on game design in unity, however I'm trying to export it into unity but all the colors turn weird. Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to accurately transfer materials from blender to unity, and you may have to remake them in unity.

Comment: are you using textures? if you do then move them first, then the mesh